# How can I add Behaviors in Styles Resources?

Tags: .net, maui

I have an animation in button click that I want to reuse without rewriting it for every button.

My code

```xml
<Button StyleClass="btn,btn-primary">
            <Button.Behaviors>
                <mct:AnimationBehavior EventName="Clicked">
                    <mct:AnimationBehavior.AnimationType >
                        <behaviorPages:ScaleAnimation 
                            Easing="{x:Static Easing.Linear}"
                            Length="100"/>
                    </mct:AnimationBehavior.AnimationType>
                </mct:AnimationBehavior>
            </Button.Behaviors>
  </Button>
```

I tried to add with `x:key`:

```xml
<Button.Behaviors x:Key="animationClick">
        <mct:AnimationBehavior EventName="Clicked">
            <mct:AnimationBehavior.AnimationType >
                <behaviorPages:ScaleAnimation 
                            Easing="{x:Static Easing.Linear}"
                            Length="100"/>
            </mct:AnimationBehavior.AnimationType>
        </mct:AnimationBehavior>
    </Button.Behaviors>
```

Comment: You can use [Animation Library for .NET MAUI](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/AlohaKit.Animations) and then define animations directly in XAML Page Resources. Consume it in Button through  `Animation="{StaticResource FadeToAnimation}" />` without rewriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Style classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0#style-classes):

Declare `behavior`namespace:

```
xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:My.Namespace;assembly=My.Assembly"
```

In `Resources` define a style class named `BehaviorButton`:

```
<Style Class="BehaviorButton" TargetType="Button">
  <Style.Behaviors>
      <behavior:MyBehavior ...

  </Style.Behaviors>
</Style>
```

Use the style class `BehaviorButton` in `Button`:

```
<Button StyleClass="BehaviorButton" ...
```

Using [Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0):

In `Resources` define a style named `BehaviorButtonStyle`. The example below also use [Style inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0#style-inheritance) using the base style `baseStyle` as indicated by `BasedOn`:

```
<Style x:Key="BehaviorButtonStyle" TargetType="Button"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
  <Style.Behaviors>
    <behavior:MyBehavior ... 

  </Style.Behaviors>
</Style>
```

Use the style `BehaviorButtonStyle` in `Button`:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BehaviorButtonStyle}" ...
```